# Jquery mobile vertical scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile site using jquery mobile here http://ilogo.in/m_/. it works good except sometimes vertical scroll stops working after adding a product into cart on product page http://ilogo.in/m_/shikamaru-shikamaru-t-shirt-105455-3105. I can not scroll the screen. this issue only occurs on mobile device. I tried to remove the ajax behaviour and refreshign the page after user clicks on buy button but it did not work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried it, it works well now. It is better if you let us know know when the issue is there !

Comment: correct url is http://ilogo.in/m_/shikamaru-shikamaru-t-shirt-105455-3105

Comment: this issue occurs after I click buy button on the product page after selecting the color and size. then vertical scroll of browser window stopped working. what mobile device you used to check it?

Comment: I am trying on iphone 6 can not see any problems !